# .Net Core The name 'Host' does not exist

Tags: .net-core, dependencies, host

I'm busy trying to get a .Net Core Host running but I keep getting a compiler error

```
error CS0103: The name 'Host' does not exist in the current context
```

I don't know if I am missing an import or package that is causing this but I am using .net core 5.0.402, the only package I added was Microsoft.AspNetCore

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TemporaryNamespace {

    public class HostClass {

        public HostClass(string[] args, string url, string port) {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    }

}
```

I'm compiling on Debian 10 by the way, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you installed the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` package?

Comment: No but it doesn't seem to complain about any of the using statements, it's pretty much a raw .net install with just the Microsoft.AspNetCore package added

Comment: That namespace comes from other packages such as `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstrations` that are bundled with `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. You still need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`

Comment: Do I need to install Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting specifically or can I install Microsoft.Extensions?

Comment: I have no idea why but adding the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` seems to have fixed it, I've never heard of this package before

Answer (score 2):

Please install Microsoft.AspNetCore.App to your project and it will work.